# LinkedHashMap что делает порядок доступа

Tags: java

У нас есть стандартный конструктор LinkedHashMap

```
   public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)
```

я не могу понять что значит accessOrder, по умолчанию LinkedHashMap хранит в порядке добавления, но если accessOrder выставить на true, то он будет хранить в порядке доступа. Объясните пожалуйста что значит порядок доступа, как он в нем хранит

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/129037/